# Python Pandas Group by and add new row with number sequence

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

```
 d = {'ID': ['H1', 'H1', 'H2', 'H2', 'H3', 'H3'], 'Year': ['2012', '2013', '2014', '2013', '2014', '2015'], 'Unit': [5, 10, 15, 7, 15, 20]}

df_input= pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df_input
```

- Group By the above df_input and wanted to get 'lag' and 'lag_u' columns. 'lag' is the number of row sequence at 'ID' and 'Year' group by level.
- 'lag_u' is just get the first Unit value at 'ID' and 'Year' group by level.

Expected Output:

```
d = {'ID': ['H1', 'H1', 'H2', 'H2', 'H3', 'H3'], 'Year': ['2012', '2013', '2014', '2013', '2014', '2015'], 'Unit': [5, 10, 15, 7, 15, 20], 'lag': [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2], 'lag_u': [5, 5, 5, 7, 7, 7]}

df_output= pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df_output
```

Comment: Please explain the logic for new columns properly.

Comment: I think problem here is groups from input data not match in ouput data.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC need [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) with [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) and [`GroupBy.first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html):

```
g = df_input.groupby('ID')
#if need group by both columns
#g = df_input.groupby(['ID','Year'])

df_input['lag'] = g.cumcount()
df_input['lag_u'] = g['Unit'].transform('first')
```